# What happens when assigning a string literal to a member const char* variable from within a constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, string, constructor, scope, literals

I saw something along these lines recently, and after quite a bit of searching I haven't found an answer that directly addresses this issue.

If I have the following code:

```
class Foo {
    const char *some_string;

    Foo()
    {
        some_string = "StringLiteral";
    }
};
```

Is this valid?

The source was pretty reputable, so my best guess is that this is acceptable, and defined behavior.

My problem with this is that it looks like the memory the string literal is being used in should be stack-allocated, and this memory should no longer be valid outside the scope of the constructor.

Looking into this, the best answer I could get is that the compiler puts the string in static memory, which would mean it is still valid outside the scope of this function.

However, like I said, all the answers I saw didn't directly reference the string literal being assigned directly from within the function itself.

So, is this valid?  And why?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal *"String literals have static storage duration, and thus exist in memory for the life of the program."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, is this valid? And why?

Yes, it's valid. Because [string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal#Notes) have static storage duration, wherever it appears (within the function body or not).

> String literals have static storage duration, and thus exist in memory for the life of the program.

Comment: Perfect.  So the other answers were correct.  Thanks!  Soon as I can accept the answer I will :)